# give discord.js user a role from client class variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'd like to be able to assign a user a role from the client variable `const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });`

I can't do it from an interaction or anything like that because the users role needs to update when I receive a 3rd party request to my server.
I tried

```
const foundUser = client.users.cache.get('userId')
foundUser.addRole('roleId')
```

But I'm not having any luck

Does anyone know how to assign/add a role from the client variable?

Answer (score 0):

It can't know in which guild you want the role to be added in. `foundUser` is a `User`, not a `Member`. You need to fetch the `Member` from a `Guild`. Also, `Member.addRole` doesn't exist.
First, add members intent to `Client`. Also add the intent in the bot tab in the discord developer portal.

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers],
});
```

Now, to add the role:

```js
client.guilds
  .fetch("guild id")
  .members.fetch("user id")
  .roles.add("role id", "reason");
```

Comment: so I did that, where you put "guild Id" I put the channel id of the channel the user is in, used id and role id were the ids for that, I checked and everything was typeof string, but it still threw this error https://imgur.com/JhYeeur . also in my ide `.members` is underlined with the warning `Unresolved variable members`. any ideas to why this all is?

Comment: it should be the id of the guild (server), not the channel id. `TextChannel.members` doesn't exist